# Passing Data to FusionChart using Javascript and MVC

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, fusioncharts

I am relatively new to both MVC and FusionCharts. I Have a View where the Model contains all the data I need, I need to pass this(or rather specific data from the model) to the FusionChart.

I have a FusionChart that I got from their site(FusionCharts), which has hard coded values, but have no idea how to replace this with the data from my model. Below is my FusionChart :

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var hourlySalesChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'multiaxisline',
        renderAt: 'chart-container2',
        width: '600',
        height: '350',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Revenue Analysis",
                "subcaption": "Last 12 weeks",
                "baseFontColor": "#333333",
                "baseFont": "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
                "xaxisname": "Week of Year",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "numvdivlines": "2",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
                "captionFontSize": "13",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "13",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "showPlotBorder": "0",
                "showXAxisLine": "1",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                "showalternatevgridcolor": "1",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                "divlineColor": "#999999",
                "divlineThickness": "1",
                "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                "divLineDashLen": "1",
                "divLineGapLen": "1",
                "xAxisLineThickness": "1",
                "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "legendShadow": "0",
                "alignCaptionWithCanvas": "0"
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        { "label": "0" },
                        { "label": "5000.00" },
                        { "label": "4000.00" },
                        { "label": "6000.00" },
                        { "label": "8000.00" },
                        { "label": "10000.00" },
                        { "label": "12000.00" },
                        { "label": "14000.00" },
                        { "label": "16000.00" }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "axis": [
                {
                    "title": "Revenue",
                    "titlepos": "left",
                    "tickwidth": "10",
                    "numberPrefix": "$",
                    "divlineisdashed": "1",
                    "dataset": [
                        {
                            "seriesname": "Revenue",
                            "linethickness": "3",
                            "data": [
                                { "value": "137500" },
                                { "value": "124350" },
                                { "value": "156700" },
                                { "value": "131450" },
                                { "value": "208300" },
                                { "value": "219900" },
                                { "value": "227500" },
                                { "value": "254300" },
                                { "value": "155900" },
                                { "value": "105650" },
                                { "value": "120950" },
                                { "value": "127500" }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "title": "Orders",
                    "axisonleft": "0",
                    "titlepos": "right",
                    "numdivlines": "8",
                    "tickwidth": "10",
                    "divlineisdashed": "1",
                    "dataset": [
                        {
                            "seriesname": "Orders",
                            "data": [
                                { "value": "22567" },
                                { "value": "21348" },
                                { "value": "24846" },
                                { "value": "19237" },
                                { "value": "20672" },
                                { "value": "23403" },
                                { "value": "30278" },
                                { "value": "26719" },
                                { "value": "21940" },
                                { "value": "24396" },
                                { "value": "22340" },
                                { "value": "25439" }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Footfalls",
                    "titlepos": "RIGHT",
                    "axisonleft": "0",
                    "numdivlines": "5",
                    "tickwidth": "10",
                    "numberSuffix": "",
                    "divlineisdashed": "1",
                    "dataset": [
                        {
                            "seriesname": "Footfalls",
                            "data": [
                                { "value": "68473" },
                                { "value": "57934" },
                                { "value": "78925" },
                                { "value": "69213" },
                                { "value": "74892" },
                                { "value": "81123" },
                                { "value": "90086" },
                                { "value": "91174" },
                                { "value": "68934" },
                                { "value": "80934" },
                                { "value": "73634" },
                                { "value": "84453" }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }).render();

});
```

I have also tried populating a string with the XML data and then did the following :

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var hourlySalesChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'multiaxisline',
        renderAt: 'chart-container2',
        width: '600',
        height: '350'
});

hourlySalesChart.setXMLData(@Model.strChartData); // - This gives an error : Incorrect Syntax
hourlySalesChart.render();
```

If anyone could help point me to the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `dataSource` is an attribute of the Object passed to the FusionCharts constructor in order to create the chart. What it holds is a JSON object. You need to have your data prepared in a way that FusionCharts understand and then can assign that to this variable. Not completely sure where the problem is actually. Here is the [basic documentation](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/installation.html).

Comment: So where the problem is, I need to replace the hard coded values with data in my Model that is passed to my View...As I explained in my question, Not completely sure where in my description this was missed...

Comment: Here are other [samples of Multi Axis Line Chart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-chart-fiddles/?type=Multi-axis--Line--Chart). Try updating your sample with the data of the other samples. All you have to do is change the value (object) of the `dataSource` property. Now after you are successful, create your own data and apply. Done.

Comment: Thanks pallabB - That is basically how I already have it. What I would like to do is prepare the data and then pass to the datasource. I can populate a string variable with the data(such as <chart ..../> etc etc, but how do I pass this to the datasource ? ive tried something like datasource : {data} (Data being the string variable), but it does not allow this. Not sure if I am making sense with that I want to do?(Perhaps because I am new to fusioncharts and MVC, this could be causing a little confusion)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and have this string assigned to a variable outside the FusionCharts code block and then assign to `dataSource`. This will help me to figure out the issue. Two problems here, `<chart ../>` is XML structure, while the above sample code uses JSON. Or there could be a problem in evaluating the variable inside the code. One scale down sample would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pallabB. There isnt an issue with the code above, it works perfect, but its all hard coded values. Ultimately all I want to do is display data from my DB into a fusion chart - Whether its done via JSON or XML I dont mind, I just dont know how to do either when it comes to passing data to the Fusionchart. I am just looking for some sample code that can explain how to do this. I have updated my question to show what I have tried now, but I am getting an error.

Comment: did you find the answer ?

Comment: I did yes, I landed up building an XML string and passed it to the Fusion Chart.